# Android: Incovertible types; cannot cast android.preference.Preference to androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference

Tags: java, android, android-layout, build.gradle

I am trying to retrieve the SeekBarPreference from the layout for my app's settings (preferences.xml). However, when I try to cast the findPreference("font_size") into a SeekBarPreference, I get the following error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast android.preference.Preference to
>   androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference

Below is my code corresponding to my settings page (MyPreferencesAcitivty.java)-the error occurs at this line:                 `final SeekBarPreference fontSizeSeekBar = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference("font_size");`:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference;

public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            // Retrieve the EditTextPreference demonstrating the font size
            final EditTextPreference fontSizeEditPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("font_size_edittext");
            // Retrive the EditText component of the EditTextPreference
            final EditText fontSizeEditText = fontSizeEditPreference.getEditText();

            // Attach a listener to the font size seekbar (changes the size of the EditText)
            final SeekBarPreference fontSizeSeekBar = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference("font_size");

        }
    }

}
```

Below is the XML code for my settings page layout (`preferences.xml`):

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.kizitonwose.colorpreference.ColorPreference
        android:defaultValue="#FF8983"
        android:title="Addition Highlight Color"
        app:colorChoices="@array/highlight_colors"
        android:key="addition_highlight_color"/>

    <com.kizitonwose.colorpreference.ColorPreference
        android:defaultValue="#99ffcc"
        android:title="Removal Highlight Color"
        app:colorChoices="@array/highlight_colors"
        android:key="removal_highlight_color"/>

    <SeekBarPreference
        android:key="font_size"
        android:title="Font Size"
        android:min="12"
        android:max="32"
        android:defaultValue="14" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="Default Value"
        android:key="font_size_edittext"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="A" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I have included the following implementation in my gradle (app-level):

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 9):

You're mixing to different systems of preferences. `SeekBarPreference` extends from `androidx.preference.Preference` while you use `android.preference.Preference`.

You have to use `androidx.preference` for all your preferences.

```
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
```

Also replace `PreferenceActivity` with `AppCompatActivity` and `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 4):

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast android.preference.Preference to
>   androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference

Casting a **`android.preference.Preference`** into **`androidx.preference.Preference`** is not proper and will get compile error as ***inconvertible*** types. Casting in Java is done within same hierarchy of types, that is between inherited types.

[**`AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace. Only the package and Maven artifact names changed; class, method, and field names did not change.

Problem coming from

```
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
```

You should use

```
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.SeekBarPreference;
import androidx.preference.EditTextPreference;
```

Your **MyPreferencesActivity** Activity will be

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pref);
    }
}
```

Your **activity_pref.xml** will be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/preferenceFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name=".MyPreferenceFragment" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Then your **MyPreferenceFragment** will be

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

        final SeekBarPreference fontSizeSeekBar = (SeekBarPreference) findPreference("font_size");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to include activity_pref.xml in main_activity.xml?

Comment: @AdamLee No, You should create layout(activity_pref) respect to MyPreferencesActivity